# req.body is undefined in a post request

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I'm trying to print to the console the content of the request's body inside a post function as follows:

```
export const createOffering = async (req, res) => {
const offering = req.body;
const newOffering = new Offering(offering);
console.log(req.body);
try{
    //await offering.save();
    res.status(201).json(newOffering);
    
}
catch(error){
    res.status(409).json({message: error.message})
}
```

}

However, the console prints "undefined"

Here is the code for my index.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import offeringsRoutes from './routes/offerings.js'

const app = express();

app.use('/offerings', offeringsRoutes);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '25mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '25mb' }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.use` is generally for middleware which you want to run before your routes. I also see that you import `bodyParser` but don't use it, and while that's not a requirement, here's how you may want to refactor:

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import offeringsRoutes from './routes/offerings.js'

const app = express();

// You generally want this middleware above your routes if you want
// them to apply to all routes that come after these.
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '25mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '25mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// If you only want to accept `POST` requests
app.post('/offerings', offeringsRoutes);
// or you can use this if you want this function to handle all requests to this route
// app.all('/offerings', offeringsRoutes);
```